# React How to subscribe for observables which is declared in another component

Tags: reactjs, redux, rxjs

I'm trying to develop a search box which filters search result in a popup while users type. A sample of my code is as follows.

```
class Search extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) { ... }

  onInputClick() {
    this.setState({...this.state, openResult: true});
  }

  onInputBlur() {
    this.setState({...this.state, openResult: false});
  }

  render() {
    return {
       <div id='search'>
         <Input onClick = {this.onInputClick} onBlur = {this.onInputBlur} />
         <Results open={this.state.open} />
       </div>
    }
  }
}
```

In the `<Input />` react component, I use the onClick and onBlur for `<input />`. Hence, when the user clicks in/out, the whole `<Search />` component gets re-rendered and based on the value of `this.state.open`, the GUI shows/hides results.

Now my problem is that I declare `let input$ = Rx.fromEvent(ref, 'input')` in the `<Input />` component. How I can filter the results in `<Result />`?

One of my solutions is to use Redux like this `input$.subscribe(data => updateReduxState(data));`. When the state is changed, the `<Result />` component gets re-rendered.

First, is it correct? Secondly, is it overkilling/overengineering? It's too complicated to use Redux + Rxjs in this way.

Comment: you can add `onChange` property on your input and connect it to your observable inside that component

Comment: I would recommend to not use observables in this case and just use redux instead, redux already provides you with a trigger to rerender components through dispatch.

Comment: You should use the normal `onChange` handler and emit it through a subject only if you need to perform stream-wise manipulations using RxJs operators such as `distinctUntilChanged`,  `debounceTime`, `takeWhile`, etc

Answer (score 0):

Your solution seems ok. I will offer pure RxJS alternative using **RxJS Subject**. Say you have two components, search component which has your `<input>` and result component which shows the data based on the search keyword.

```
__________        __________
| search |        | result |
|        |   -->  |        |
|________|        |________|
```

What you can do is, create a `subject` and emit values through it on blur out or key up based on your requirement.
Let result component subscribe to that subject and listen for values.
Based on the keyword in search box run the function for evaluating result and show them in result component.
This way you eliminate redux.

Pseudo code can be something like,

`searchComponent`

```
searchboxSubject = new Subject<any>();

blurOut(event) {
   this.searchboxSubject.next(event); //event holds your search keyword.
}
```

`resultComponent`

```
searchboxSubject.subscribe((data) => this.evaluateResultAndUpdateUI(data));
```

Comment: In theory, it's correct. However, my question is how to subscribe from another component.

Comment: I am from Angular background, so in that, I would create a service. In that service I will define the rxjs subject.`searchSubject = new Subject();` Inject that service in both the components. In search component use the subject to send search keyword `myservice.searchSubject.next(keyword)`. In result component use subject to listen to the value and evaluate result `myservice.searchSubject.subscribe();. I am sure there must be service concept in React as well.

Answer (score 0):

At the end, I didn't use this approach `input$.subscribe(data => updateReduxState(data))`. Instead I just use setState() for  parent component. Just a recap, `input$` is declared within  component so I need to pass onChange handler like this `<Input onChange={Search.onChange()} />`

My code has been working really nice. My friends also like the search box. You can give it a try here: https://gokien.info/all-forums